# Does "prioritary" exist outside technical texts?

Tags: vocabulary, translation, non-native-english

As a non-native speaker, I'm struggling to express correctly the sense of priority of a given population in a sentence.

Is it correct to refer to "***prioritary*** cities in the scope of the XYZ policy", meaning "cities over which priority has been given in the scope..."?

I don't think so. I've found several occurrences of "prioritary" with similar meaning on English books authored by non-native speakers, and it seems to be of common usage in other technical (programming) forums. On the other hand, the English dictionaries don't have an entry for it, and Google suggested that the word may be a misspelling.

I should note that there is an equivalent word at least in Portuguese and Spanish.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: *Prioritary* is a mathematical term and almost unheard of outside of mathematics. Whether it is "correct" or not therefore depends on what kind of writing you are doing for what kind of work addressed to what kind of audience. It is possible that like *planification* or *actorness*, it has entered non-native usage via mistranslations from words like the Italian *prioritari* or the French *prioritaire*.

Comment: the adjective in English is priority. The Romance languages have a different form for the adjective. Not English. There is a lot of very bad translation out there. I know since I am asked to correct and proofread text like that all the time. We say: priority [noun] in English. So, don't waste your time.....

Comment: I don't recognize this word. What is it supposed to mean? I can't seem to figure out was intended by the example given.

Comment: Thanks choster and Lambie, I will stick with "priority". And thanks Mitch, I have edited the question to clarify the meaning intended for "prioritary".

Comment: Even the phrase “over which priority has been given in the scope” is awkward and difficult to interpret. Does it mean that during the execution of the XYZ policy, some cities will receive the benefit of the policy before others (or even instead of others)? Unless there is a specific technical term with a very specific meaning in your discipline, I would think simpler language is better.

Comment: @David K, thanks for the comment. Yes, the meaning is (would be) exactly what you said. I'm assuming that the very usage of priority in the proposed context is not as straightforward in English as it is in other languages, not to say the original use in my question. Any suggestions on an alternative construction to better express the idea?

Comment: I think that the likeliest model for recent, nonspecialist efforts to build _prioritary_ from _priority_ is _proprietary_ built from _propriety_.

Comment: I would say 'prioritised cities', myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Prioritary*, as it appears in scholarly works, is a term from algebraic geometry for a concept I am not qualified to describe even in the vaguest terms. This sense is far from common in English, however, and does not appear in any major dictionary or in the OED.

As an adjective, *priority* is usually synonymous with *high priority*, i.e. assigned a higher degree of importance or attention: a *priority client*, *priority boarding*, a *priority transmission from Starfleet*, and probably, *priority cities in the scope of the XYZ policy*.

As a noun, however, *priority* can refer either to the order of precedence in general— you might triage your email inbox into high-priority, normal priority, and low-priority messages— or to the assignment of a higher order of precedence or attention to something.

Some languages appear to employ different words to make the distinction, e.g. *priorité* and *prioritaire*, *приоритет* and *приоритетный*, but English does not. Where you see *prioritary* in a non-mathematical context, therefore, I would suppose it to be a mistranslation.

Similarly, the verb to *prioritize* refers both to the general evaluation of something for its importance and to the assignment of a high level of importance to something. Thus, *this filter prioritizes messages from clients* can mean *either* that it evaluates and assigns a priority to the messages from clients, *or* that it assigns a high priority to all messages from clients and a lower priority to other messages. *These messages are prioritized* is similarly ambiguous. Additional context is required to understand which meaning is intended.